# sed command to be used to modify the file name

Tags: bash, sed

I am able to use the sed command for a simple things but I have a question which for me is complex to find the solution by my own, so if some one can help me it would be a great favour.

example: how shall I modify the following file as following?

```
orig_file_name = OBIEE_S99_TT_PLV_BI0026.rpd
target_file_name = OBIEE_S99_TT_PLV.rpd
```

so in my bash script, I will be doing following.
1. check the latest file in a directory.
2. pickup that file and modify its name, similar as above.

situations: I do not know always what would be the file name is, but i know the part of pattern, file names always ends as "something_is_name_xxxx.rpd"
so then I would want to modify the file name as "something_is_name.rpd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, but i don't doubt there are better solutions.

```
for f in $(ls -1t OBIEE_S99_TT_PLV* | head -1)
do
    mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/_BI[0-9]*//g')
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you **know** the filenames follow the pattern you described, you can use

```
target_file_name="${orig_file_name%_*}.${orig_file_name##*.}"
```

Here `${orig_file_name%_*}` is the part of the filename before the last `_`, and `${orig_file_name##*.}` is the part after the last `.`. Which is always `rpd`, come to think of it, so

```
target_file_name="${orig_file_name%_*}.rpd"
```

would also work in your case.

These expansions are bash-specific. They are described in greater detail in the bash man page under "Parameter Expansion."

Comment: those expansions work in all `ksh` versions. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

I would use sed with this regex:

```
$ echo OBIEE_S99_TT_PLV_BI0026.rpd | sed "s/^\(.*\)\(_[a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)\(\.rpd\)$/\1\3/g"
OBIEE_S99_TT_PLV.rpd
```

1. this assumes that your file extension will be always rpd, but can be
   easily changed
2. you may not need parentheses escaping in a script

Answer (score 0):

```
man rename
```

could help, no sed, but perl.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many underscores you have?
Change string starting with the last underscore:

```
echo OBIEE_S99_TT_PLV_BI0026.rpd | sed 's/_[a-zA-Z0-9]*.rpd$/.rpd/'
```

Other answers can be better, depending on the exact restrictions what you know.
You might even use cut when you know a fixed number of underscores:

```
echo $(echo OBIEE_S99_TT_PLV_BI0026.rpd | cut -d_ -f1-4).rpd
```